# How to Launch a compiled MATLAB program from C Project using MATLAb Engine

Tags: c, windows, matlab

Using: Windows 10, Matlab R2019b and VS2012.

I am currently using the Matlab Engine calling: engOpen(), in a compiled C program to launch a Matlab Command Window.   Once this command window is opened I am using functions like: engEvalString() and engPutVariable() to pass data and process this data in MATLAB.  This all works well on my MATLAB development PC but in the long run I would like to deploy on a non-development PC, meaning MATLAB would not be installed but rather a compiled MATLAB program is installed.  So it it possible to use the MATLAB Engine COM methodology from a C program to open and communicate to a compiled MATLAB program?  If so can you suggest reference material or provide an example?

Thank You!

Comment: what is a compiled MATLAB program? You can translate MATLAB code to C code to have really standalone programs, the other options will always require the MATLAB runtime to be installed (and licensed)

Comment: MATLAB provides a compiler so that MATLAB programs can be deployed on non-licensed machines.  I will need to deploy on many computers and purchasing a license for each machine would be too costly.

Comment: Oh I see, you're talking about the Application Compiler. Well, if you want to call it from C code, try to use the MATLAB Coder right away. That will generate C code from MATLAB code and you don't have to fiddle how to interface with a MATLAB runtime

Comment: `engEvalString` is never going to work in the free MATLAB runtime, because it basically allows to use all of MATLAB rather than just the code that was compiled. You need to write a MATLAB function that gets data, processes it, and returns it. Then compile this into a DLL. You can then load the DLL and call the MATLAB function from your C code. There are many examples for this in the documentation and elsewhere online.